# Managed property is not getting populated post crawl

Tags: sharepoint-server, managed-property, crawled-property

The HTML file is,

```
<html>
    <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8" />
             <meta name="Duration" content="265" />
    </head>
    <body></body>
 </html>
```

I crawled the above webpage, the crawled property is Duration.

I created a corresponding managed property named "Duration" to the crawled property and made it as queryable, searchable, refinable.

I have crawled once again but the value of crawled property is not getting reflected in managed property.

Answer (score 1):

After creating or changing a managed property, to make the changes of the managed property work, you need to do a full crawl for your content source.

So, for your issue, please do a full crawl for your content source.